# Saving frames as images using FFmpeg

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

There are some tutorials on the internet about it, most of them is using deprecated functions and unfortunately the API use to broke and it makes a mess and I'm really confused.

I'm following tutorials, learning with the documentation and seeing the examples of the current version (even that way some examples does not work).

What I'm trying to do is to save frames in `.png`, following the examples and reading I did this, but I'm confused about the conversion the frame to RBG and saving it:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libavutil/avutil.h>
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        av_log(0, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Usage: %s <input>", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    const char * filename = argv[1];

    // register all codecs and formats
    av_register_all();

    // open input file, and allocate format context
    AVFormatContext *avFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();

    if (avformat_open_input(&avFormatContext, filename, 0, 0) < 0)
    {
        av_log(0, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Could not open source file %s", filename);
        return -1;
    }

    // retrieve stream information
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(avFormatContext, 0) < 0)
    {
        av_log(0, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Could not find stream information");
        return -1;
    }

    // dump information about file onto standard error
    av_dump_format(avFormatContext, 0, filename, 0);

    // find the "best" video stream in the file.
    int result = av_find_best_stream(avFormatContext, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, 0, 0);

    if (result < 0)
    {
        av_log(0, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Could not find %s stream in input file '%s'", av_get_media_type_string(AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO), filename);
        return -1;
    }

    int stream = result;
    AVStream *avStream = avFormatContext->streams[stream];
    AVCodecContext *avCodecContext = avStream->codec;

    // find decoder for the stream
    AVCodec *avCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(avCodecContext->codec_id);

    if (! avCodec)
    {
        av_log(0, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Failed to find %s codec", av_get_media_type_string(AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO));
        return -1;
    }

    // init the decoders, with reference counting
    AVDictionary *avDictionary = 0;
    av_dict_set(&avDictionary, "refcounted_frames", "1", 0);

    if (result = avcodec_open2(avCodecContext, avCodec, &avDictionary) < 0)
    {
        av_log(0, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Failed to open %s codec", av_get_media_type_string(AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO));
        return -1;
    }

    AVFrame *avFrame = av_frame_alloc();

    if (! avFrame)
    {
        av_log(0, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Could not allocate frame");
        return -1;
    }

    // initialize packet, set data to null, let the demuxer fill it
    AVPacket avPacket;
    av_init_packet(&avPacket);
    avPacket.data = 0;
    avPacket.size = 0;

    while (av_read_frame(avFormatContext, &avPacket) >= 0)
    {
        if (avPacket.stream_index == stream)
        {
            int success = avcodec_decode_video2(avCodecContext, avFrame, &success, &avPacket);

            if (success <= 0)
            {
                av_log(0, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Error decoding video frame");
                return -1;
            }

            // ... saving...
        }
    }

    avcodec_close(avCodecContext);
    avformat_close_input(&avFormatContext);
    av_frame_free(&avFrame);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's unclear what your question is.

Comment: "Saving frames as images using FFmpeg" - "What I'm trying to do is to save frames in `.png`" - unclear?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to save that frame in `.png` file (the right way).